# Using "_Problem Steps Recorder" with the Stop Event

Tags: python, problem-steps-recorder

I'm using *psr.exe* in my python application and I'm trying to somehow get a signal from *psr* when it saves the recording file.

I saw that there's an option in *psr* called *stopevent* which somehow sends an event after it stops recording and saves the recording file.
But there's no documentation about how to use this parameter **anywhere**.

So the question is, How can I use the *stopevent* parameter in my program to get an event after the *psr* successfully saves the recording file?